# what can I use instead of "less well defined"?

Tags: vocabulary

I have 2 models. Model-2 is more ambiguous than Model-1. I want to say Model-2 is less well defined, but it sounds strange already. What can I use instead of less well-defined?

Comment: Why not just “more ambiguous”, as you say, if that is indeed the case? If you want a “less” term, you could say “less structured”, “less defined”, or others like this, but it may well depend on precisely what kind of definition you’re talking about.

Comment: Is it the model that is ambiguous or the results produced by the model that are ambiguous? It's hard to know exactly what you are trying to say.

Comment: The literal opposite is "more poorly defined," which sounds a little more idiomatic to me. Another better option is "not as well defined".